# Inconsistent? Hamiltonians for a scalar field in the presence of a classical source

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, hamiltonian

Consider a real scalar field
\begin{equation}
\phi(x)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\left(a_pe^{-ip\cdot x}+a_p^{\dagger}e^{ip\cdot x} \right).
\end{equation}

In Chapter 2 of Peskin, right after Eq. 2.64, we have the form of the hamiltonian for a real scalar field coupled to a classical source $j(x)$:
$$1) \qquad H =\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}E_p\left(a_p^{\dagger}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\tilde{j}^*(p) \right)\left(a_p+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\tilde{j}(p) \right),$$
where $\tilde{j}(p)=\int d^4y e^{ip\cdot y}j(y)$.

On the other hand, the hamiltonian which describes such a system is given by
\begin{equation}
2)  \qquad  H=H_0-\int d^3x j(x)\phi(x).
\end{equation}

I want to see that these two expressions for the hamiltonian are indeed equivalent. By expanding the first one we obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
H&=&\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}E_p a_p^{\dagger}a_p+\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}i\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{2}}\left(a_p^{\dagger}\tilde{j}(p) -a_p\tilde{j}^*(p)\right)+\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{|\tilde{j}(p)|^2}{2}\\
&=&H_0+\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}i\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{2}}\left(a_p^{\dagger}\tilde{j}(p) -a_p\tilde{j}^*(p)\right)+\langle 0|H| 0 \rangle.
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\langle 0|H| 0 \rangle$ is a constant term we can ignore it. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
H=H_0+\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}i\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{2}}\left(a_p^{\dagger}\tilde{j}(p) -a_p\tilde{j}^*(p)\right).
\end{equation}

Notice
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}i\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{2}}\left(a_p^{\dagger}\tilde{j}(p) -a_p\tilde{j}^*(p)\right)&=&\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi^3)}i\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{2}}\left(\int d^4x j(x)\left(a_p^{\dagger}e^{ip\cdot y}-a_pe^{-ip\cdot y} \right)\right)\\
&=&\int d^4x j(x)\left[\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}i\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{2}}\left(a_p^{\dagger}e^{ip\cdot x}-a_pe^{-ip\cdot x} \right)\right]\\
&=&\int d^4x j(x)\dot{\phi}(x).
\end{eqnarray}
That would leave us with the expression
\begin{equation}
1) \quad H = H_0+\int d^4x j(x)\dot{\phi}(x).
\end{equation}

Thus, from $1)$ and $2)$ we would expect
\begin{equation}
\int d^4x j(x)\dot{\phi}(x)=-\int d^3x j(x)\phi(x).
\end{equation}
To be more explicit, this actually is
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^t dt' \int d^3x j(t',\mathbf{x})\dot{\phi}(t',\mathbf{x})=-\int d^3x j(t,\mathbf{x})\phi(t,\mathbf{x}),
\end{equation}
where $t$ is some time after the source is turned off.

MY QUESTION IS: how can we prove that these two expressions are equivalent?
I tried to do it for the case where $j(x)$ varies very slowly, so its time derivative is very small and we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int d^4yj(y)\dot{\phi}(y)&=&\int_{-\infty}^{t} dt'\int d^3yj(t',\mathbf{y})\frac{\partial \Phi(t',\mathbf{y})}{\partial t'}\\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^{t} dt'\int d^3y\frac{\partial [j(t',\mathbf{y})\Phi(t',\mathbf{y})]}{\partial t'}\\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^{t} dt'\frac{d [\int d^3yj(t',\mathbf{y})\Phi(t',\mathbf{y})]}{d t'}\\
&=&\int d^3yj(t,\mathbf{y})\Phi(t,\mathbf{y}),
\end{eqnarray}
but still wet a wrong sign! Moreover, Peskin does not assume a slowly varying $j(x)$, so in principle the analysis should be valid for any source in the past.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just made a sign error somewhere?